# Retrieve JSON value using PHP json_decode

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve a value from JSON that's returned from an API, however I can't seem to work out how to get there! Below is what is being returned and how I'm currently trying to access it:

```
array(1) { ["ticket"]=> array(17) { ["id"]=> int(707078) ["subject"]=> string(6) "werwer" ["replies_count"]=> int(0) ["comments_count"]=> int(0) ["last_activity_at"]=> string(20) "2013-05-03T10:13:52Z" ["created_at"]=> string(20) "2013-05-03T10:13:52Z" ["unanswered"]=> bool(true) ["archived"]=> bool(false) ["spam"]=> bool(false) ["trash"]=> bool(false) ["summary"]=> string(9) "werewrwer" ["source"]=> array(1) { ["web"]=> string(3) "api" } ["cc"]=> array(0) { } ["labels"]=> array(0) { } ["requester"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(249190) ["email"]=> string(22) "steven@frontpage.co.uk" ["name"]=> string(6) "steven" ["agent"]=> bool(true) ["picture"]=> array(6) { ["thumb20"]=> string(81) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=20" ["thumb24"]=> string(81) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=24" ["thumb32"]=> string(81) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=32" ["thumb48"]=> string(81) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=48" ["thumb64"]=> string(81) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=64" ["thumb128"]=> string(82) "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9baabb86969cbccb6230d298a04f3490.png?r=PG&s=128" } } ["content"]=> array(4) { ["html"]=> string(9) "werewrwer" ["text"]=> string(9) "werewrwer" ["truncated"]=> bool(false) ["attachments"]=> array(0) { } } ["starred"]=> bool(false) } }

$jsonResponse = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
die($jsonResponse['ticket']['id']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong except not paying attention to the fact that the *type* of the argument to `die` (an alias for [`exit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)) matters:

> If `status` is a string, this function prints the status just before
>   exiting.
>
> **If `status` is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed.** Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.
>
> Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.

So you would get the expected behavior if you did this instead:

```
echo $jsonResponse['ticket']['id'];
die;
```

Or even this:

```
die((string)$jsonResponse['ticket']['id']);
```

Comment: @RMcLeod: No, he's doing that correctly. You are confused because the wording of the question is not quite correct.

Comment: @Jon Don't worry. This is a **really good catch** and **the correct answer** +1

Comment: No, he's using json_decode() on a var_dump serialization of an array... the problem lies outside the code he posted here.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: Again: no, he's not doing that. You think he does because the wording is off. It should be obvious by the second argument to `json_decode`.

Comment: Good catch @Jon I see what he's done now, I rescind my downvote

Comment: @StevenMoseley as Jon said he's poorly worded his question, I thought the same as you but look again

Comment: @StevenMoseley: Since we can only *assume* what the contents of `$jsonResponse` are (there is no actual code that prints it), I really don't see how you can be so sure.

Comment: Yeah.... I'm with you guys now... sorry for that.  Give your post an edit and I'll change my vote.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: No problem, happens to all of us. Edited.

Comment: It won't let me know mark the question as answered, but this is correct! Thanks a lot Jon, smart guy! Apologies for all downvotes as well as the mistyped question.

Comment: Upvoted...  @smclintock - there's a checkmark outline next to his answer.  Click that to mark it correct.

Comment: Ignore that garbled response, meant to say it wouldn't let me mark it because of the time limit, that's it marked now.